# Will this kind of solution be accepted by Apple?

Tags: iphone, app-store, mfi

I found this site:

http://www.perceptdev.com/labs/content/iphone-infrared-receiver-using-iphone-20-sdk-no-jailbreak-required

(iPhone infrared receiver - using iPhone 2.0 SDK, no jailbreak required!)

Will Apple accept this type of app and harware?

Anyone have idea or expirience?

Comment: Nice solution :) - I wish i could help with an answer - i tend to believe that they have no reason of rejecting an app like this, but this is to they discretion ...

Comment: They have rules, the question is if this breaks any rule!

Answer (score 0):

You need a MFi license. Is the only way to be 100% sure your APP and hardware will be accepted by Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

MFi (Made for iPhone)

Comment: Thank you. Even a standard jack needs this license? I mean a standard audio headphone?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES!!!!!!!!!!!
I found this app in the appstore:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/square/id335393788?mt=8